# Plot a 1D array on 3 radii in a polar heat map

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap, polar-coordinates

I have a 3 1D arrays: radius, angle and temperature. Together they form a 2D temperature map of a ring. 
The arrays take the form:

```
r = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]
th = [0.,0.78539816,1.57079633,2.35619449,3.14159265,3.92699082,4.71238898,5.49778714,6.28318531]
z = [-1,2,5,2,4,-1,3,2,3]
```

I don't understand how I can make those z data fall on the right coordinates.

I can make it work, with random numbers, using the following simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

rad = np.linspace(.2, 1, 4)
azm = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 9)
r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, azm)
z = np.random.rand(9,4) ** th * r
ax0 = plt.subplot(projection="polar")
im = plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z, cmap='bwr')
plt.plot(azm, r, color='k', ls='none')
plt.axis('off')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
ax0.set_title('3 radii polar heat map')
```

[This is how my example code comes out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT1zz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended splitting the list `z` into 3 lists and made a matrix out of them using `z_mat = np.array([z1,z2,z3])`. I took care that the lists for `rad` and `azm` contained one item more than `z`, which is a requirement for `pcolormesh`. After that I transposed the matrix to have the same dimensions as `r` and `th` using `z_mat_trans = z_mat.transpose()`